# How to authenticate user for accessing site in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have one global site. I have created another site using liferay. I need to restrict the access to this site for guest user. Whenever I write the URL for accessing the site, it should ask me for the authentication. If user is authenticated and user of the portal then only user can able to view the contents on the site.

I need to modify the guest role or provide some authentication to site.

How can I achieve this in liferay 6.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use servlet filter hook and session attribute:

- if the URL matches your site, then check session for some custom
  attribute.
- and if necessary, do redirect to authentication page